# Radio button not clickable Contact form 7

Tags: html, css

For a contact form I use radio button with labels.

For the label I used:

```css
    background-image: url(https://www.dedroogbouwvloer.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/css-keuze.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    background-position: 0 0;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
```

For the radio button I used

input[type=radio]

```css
position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: -1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    left: -1000px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
```

Problem is that I cannot click the radio button. Page on: https://www.dedroogbouwvloer.nl/prijscalculatie-droogbouwvloer/

Answer (score 1):

If i go to this page the radio buttons are clickable. Also in contact form 7 you make a radio button like this: [checkbox your-country "China" "India" "San Marino"]

Comment: Yes but they are not getting selected once you click on the button

Comment: Could you clarify this some more? Are the not getting send with the email? If so in the case of [checkbox* your-country "China" "India" "San Marino"] the * makes it a required field and in the mail you can use [your-country] to write the value in the e-mail